# Group and sum by row in R

Tags: r, rows, data-manipulation

that is my first question on Stack. I am looking for an efficient way to group and sum values inside a row. 
My data in row is  distributed that way: 10000 10 20000 20 40000 12 60000 23 10000 12 40000 17. 
I need a result: 10000 22 20000 20 40000 29 60000 23. Big numbers are characteristics, smaller - occurences.

[image: example of row from data]

Thats my real data - for example for 10004 I need 23.
I tried with loops, aggregate, but I cannot do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `aggregate`

```
## Your data
Row = c(11131132, 10004, 5, 265098, 3, 190029, 2, 
    265092, 2, 265077, 17, 10004, 18, 
    265097,17, 265098,15,190029,2, 265099,17)

ID    = Row[seq(2,length(Row), 2)]
value = Row[seq(3,length(Row), 2)]
GroupSum = aggregate(value, list(ID), sum)
GroupSum
  Group.1  x
1   10004 23
2  190029  4
3  265077 17
4  265092  2
5  265097 17
6  265098 18
7  265099 17
```